# How to write test cases for IBM MQ using Embedded MQ?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I am new to IBM MQ and don't have any background. I have followed the below link for code development.

https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/

I am trying to figure out how to write/test IBM MQ using an embedded MQ server (For eg: Embedded Kafka), but unable to identify the solution. Can anyone help me with the following queries,

1. Do we have any Embedded MQ server support which can be used to test IBM MQ with Spring Boot application?
2. If yes, Can you please share some examples of how to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the documentation at this git hub repo - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

Extract from the readme:

> IBM MQ JMS Spring Components
>
> This repository contains code to help to provide Spring developers
> with easy configuration of the IBM MQ JMS package.
>
> The library contains:
>
> mq-jms-spring-boot-starter for Spring Boot 2 applications

Comment: Maybe MQ Advanced for developers or the docker version would meet the requirement?

Comment: That is a good point. The ibmcom/mq image will give you a dockerised MQ Advanced for developers. There is a get started tutorial - https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-containers/ 
and there are Spring docker images available.

Comment: Thanks, @chughts I have implemented IBM MQ (Docker image) for PUB-SUB, and for testing, I have used an Embedded Active MQ server.